# Vb.net Mouse location

Tags: vb.net, location, cursor, mouse

I try to make a maze. When mouse hit the wall it need to go back to panel1 position and it going back, but when i move the mouse it coming back where i hit the wall and the event is useless. I can go to finish through the wall.
[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiRrFSU564E).

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Start()
    Dim StartPoint = Panel1.Location()
    StartPoint.Offset(20, 20)
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(StartPoint)
End Sub

Private Sub Finish_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label17.MouseEnter
    MessageBox.Show("Gz")
End Sub

Private Sub WallHit_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseEnter, Panel1.MouseEnter, Label9.MouseEnter, Label8.MouseEnter, Label7.MouseEnter, Label6.MouseEnter, Label5.MouseEnter, Label4.MouseEnter, Label3.MouseEnter, Label2.MouseEnter, Label16.MouseEnter, Label15.MouseEnter, Label14.MouseEnter, Label13.MouseEnter, Label12.MouseEnter
    Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I run my app in a virtual machine (windows 10). The problem appear when i run in vm but when i run it in outside of vm my app work correctly.